# Text with superscript in matplotlib, rendered as a single string

Tags: matplotlib, vector-graphics

When making tick labels with superscripts (e.g. on a log-log plot), matplotlib renders each digit in a label as a separate text object in PDF. Is there a way to make matplotlib render entire label as one string, with characters of different kinds (regular and superscript)?

It is important when trying to edit/resize plot in a vector editor. Currently I have to re-do all tick labels manually as the split tick labels get misaligned.

Answer (score -2):

You may refer to the official tutorial using Latex language [https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html]

Comment: Latex renders each symbol as a separate letter. Latex plots are impossible to edit in vector format as a result. If you up the font, for example, spacing won't change and it will look ugly.